# Voice Over not focusing on UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, voiceover

I am trying to set up the accessibility for a paginated `UICollectionView`, so VoiceOver would say "[Cell 1 description], Page 1 of 5", but VoiceOver focuses on the `UICollectionViewCell` itself, so the user doesn't know that is pagination.

It is strange that the three finger swipe pagination works in accessibility mode, just does not enter by default.

Does anybody know how tell Voice Over that the UICollectionView is an accessibility element, not the cells?

```
let goalsArr: [String] = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]

@IBOutlet weak var goalsCollectionView: UICollectionView!

func setup() {
    goalsCollectionView.dataSource = self
    goalsCollectionView.delegate = self
    goalsCollectionView.isAccessibilityElement = true
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    guard let cell = goalsCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: goalCellXib, for: indexPath) as? ASGoalCollectionViewCell else {
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }

    cell.lblText.text = goalsArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.isAccessibilityElement = true
    cell.accessibilityLabel = "cell " + goalsArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Already tried to set the cells as `.isAccessibilityElement = false`, but then VoiceOver skips the `UICollectionView` entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way to reach your purpose is to:

- Define your collection view as a `UIAccessibilityElement` subclass.
- Set its trait to `.adjustable` in order to select the different elements by swiping right or left.
- Adapt the label and the value according to the selected cell.
- Define the collection view [accessibilityElements].

It may be tedious but that's what Apple's engineers recommend ⟹ a [complete and detailed example](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-18230.html#Demo) is introduced in a WWDC session, don't hesitate to take a look at it to perfectly implement your collection view for VoiceOver.